# YouTube API Fetch sends Response, but I cannot access Items

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, fetch

Other questions on the issue I've encountered seem to center on having an incorrect key, but I think I have that covered and now I'm stumped . . .  is it the issue with YouTube API or the `fetch()`?

In simplified terms I'm sending:

```
export function loadVideo() {
  fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=25&order=relevance&q=WOODYGUTHRIE&topicId=%2Fm%2F04rlf&type=video&videoCaption=any&key=MYKEY")
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(queryString);
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  console.log(videoList);
}
```

And just looking at my logs, that query string will load the JSON I want in my browser just fine, and logging the `response` itself gives me:

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=…n=any&key=MYKEY", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: ""
type: "cors"
url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=25&order=relevance&q=WOODYGUTHRIE&topicId=%2Fm%2F04rlf&type=video&videoCaption=any&key=MYKEY"
__proto__: Response
```

BUT anyway I slice it, `response.items`, `response.body.items`, `response.data.items`, I get `undefined`. So I'm grasping at straws and can't see a clear path in my troubleshooting yet.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: can you please provide us with the content of the body property, It should be an object which contains many other objects or arrays. It would be helpfull to see the structure of theese object, at least till the object or property which contains the information you need and want to extract.

Comment: First step it to put the finished url in a browser to see if the API returns what you think it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) to allow javascript to be able to parse through it so it should probably be something like the following:

```
export function loadVideo() {
  fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=25&order=relevance&q=WOODYGUTHRIE&topicId=%2Fm%2F04rlf&type=video&videoCaption=any&key=MYKEY")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => {
    //Do something with the result like
    console.log(result.items)
  });  
}
```

Comment: Badda boom badda bing. Thanks brother! Perhaps my disconnect came because I previously had this API call happening within an `$.ajax()`, but I'm dropping the jQuery for this updated project, and did not need to parse within the `success` parameter there.

Answer (score 0):

The [examples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#Sample_Partial_Requests) show the response should have a `videos` field as a list/array.
Can you check if your response object has such a field?